# Custom-sized persistence storage for Tails on USB flash drive

Tags: linux, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, luks, tails

I've been trying out tails on a USB flash drive. By default, when I create the persistence storage, it fills up the entire remaining space of the flash drive. This basically makes the flash drive useless for any "typical" usage, i.e. a simple, cross-OS storage device, because the encrypted storage is a pain to mount in many OS.

What I was hoping to do is:

- install Tails on the flash drive in it's default FAT32 partition (the installer does this automatically)
- create a partition with the persistence storage that doesn't fill up the drive

I can't pre-create the partitions as far as I can tell because the Tails installer will wipe everything. I can't resize the persistence luks partition because gparted and other tools don't seem to support it (yet). I found some command line instructions to resize on the command line, but the process was very complex and frankly quite scary.

So, to the point: **how can I create the persistence storage with a custom size, or are there clear instructions on how to resize that partition?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found a simple workaround.

The "trick" is that when you run *configure persistent storage* in tails to create the encrypted volume, it will fill up *unallocated* space on it's device. So if you first create a partition of your liking and leave as much as you like left for the luks volume, you can control it's size.

### Steps

- Install Tails onto a USB flash drive as usual, i.e. using the tails-installer utility
- Using a partitioning tool (e.g. gparted, disks), create a FAT32 volume of desired size following the partition that was created for tails by the installer
- Boot into tails and run *configure persistent storage* tool as usual. It will fill the remaining unallocated space on your flash drive with the persistence storage.

### Result

Here's how it looks on a test 4GB flash drive of mine. Highlighted are the FAT32 volume I wanted to have for typical flash drive use (named **half**), as well as the encrypted partition created by tails for persistence (named **TailsData**).

[image]

Now I can plug the drive into any old OS and use the "half" partition, or boot into Tails and use the encrypted persistence storage (as well as the unencrypted FAT32 partition).